# 2D Pointer Arithmetic for grabbing Individual Row and Individual Column

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array misunderstanding that I am just not comprehending. I checked all on the forums to find a way to resolve this but to no avail.

The situation, I have a 2D array and using my `findTile()` function I want to be able to take an individual row from it using pointer arithmetic. Correspondingly I also want to be taking entire columns?

The method header is as is and can't be changed. If I find a tile X (where x is a number and a tile is just an array unit) then I want to able to manipulate it along the directions (up, down, left, right). All surrounding values in the array will shift accordingly and they wrap. So in an array

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]
```

"up 9" would mean

```
[1][2][6]
[4][5][9]
[7][8][3]
```

"left 3" would mean

```
[1][2][6]
[4][5][9]
[8][3][7]
```

So if only I could find out how to manipulate these rows as columns, that would be great, but then, that's the problem. I must use my `findTile()` function in my `moveDirection()` function and I do not know what I can assign to the parameters that are indicated as '?'.

```
static bool findTile(int tile, int rows, int cols, int grid[][cols], int *r, int *c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (grid[i][j] == tile)
            {
                r = grid[i];
                c = grid[j];
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool moveLeft(int tile, int rows, int cols, int grid[][cols])
{
    findTile(tile, rows, cols, grid, ?, ?);
}
```

Please if you can enlighten me on what pointer techniques there are to solve this issue maybe that would grant me some insight on how to deal with a problem like this. I am not very experienced in C.

Comment: Do some searching for *emulating pass by reference in c*.

Comment: `r = grid[i]; c = grid[j];` --> `*r = i; *c = j;` ?

Comment: Step 1 is to realize that C does not specify how a 2D array is used. What dimension that's rows and which one that's columns in your 2D array is up to you to specify.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues, the use of a pointer argument in a function and how to pass such an argument to the function.

First, your function argument `int *r` is a pointer to an integer; dereferencing it reads/writes the integral value it points to. In contrast, using it "plain" like in `r = grid[i]` lets the pointer point to a different place (to the address of the first element of the i'th row in this case), which is probably not what you want. I suppose you meant `*r = i`, which writes the value of `i` into the place where `r` points to.

Second, when calling the function, provide a pointer to an integral object into which the function can write the result.

Hence, it will be something like the following:

```
static bool findTile(int tile, int rows, int cols, int grid[][cols], int *r, int *c) {
   ...
   *r = 10;
   ...
   return true;
}

int main() {

   int r=0, c=0;
   findTile(... , &r, &c); // Note: & passes the address of integral objects r and c
   // after that, r has the value 10
}
```

Comment: This is understandable, only, assigning 10 to r is not what I am trying to achieve here. I am trying to get an entire row. And entire columns from this. I understand if I say `r = grid`, that points to `grid[0]`, so maybe if grid at 0 was `grid[0]={3,1,2}` then I want to be able to use r to manipulate that entire row. If that makes sense.